# What does this code mean, need reassurance...Java Basics

Tags: java

Hi this is probably easy for most of you guys but I was given this code to analyze in class today and I'm just starting out with Java I was wondering if someone could fill me in on of the rest of the code means which I  really do not understand. However, I do understand some parts where I have put the // marks.

```
   **I have no clue about this following statement**

public class PONG extends JComponent implements ActionListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {

    **are these the initial values?**


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private int scorefinal;
            private int ballx = 150;
            private int bally = 30;
            private int ballx1 = 100;
            private int bally1 = 10;
            private int paddlex = 0;
            private int ballySpeed = 7;
            private int ballxSpeed = 5;
            private int bally1Speed = 14;
            private int ballx1Speed = 10;

            public int score = 0;
            public int score1 = 0;
            public int bestscore;
            public int bestscore1;
            public boolean gameOver, started;
        **Is this saying how fast the ball moves?**


Timer tt = new Timer(10, g);
        tt.start();

        }
    **I do not know the following block of code**
        public void newball(int ballx, int bally, int ballxspeed, int       ballyspeed) {

            ballx = 150; 
            bally = 30;
            ballxspeed = 5;
            ballyspeed = 7;
            return;
        }
            **So how is the scoring calculated?**   
            if (score >= 5) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 8, 50));
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(score + score1), 30 / 1 - 15, 80);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.white);
                g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 8, 50));
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(score), 30 / 1 - 15, 80);
            }
            // start && gameOver
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", 8, 50));

            if (gameOver) {
    **I do not understand the 50/ 1-15, 200**
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(" Best Score :" + scorefinal), 50 / 1 - 15, 200);

            }
        }


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            ballx = ballx + ballxSpeed;
            bally = bally + ballySpeed;


**I think these are the boundaries but i am not entirely sure
            // Window Down 
            if (ballx >= paddlex && ballx <= paddlex + 100 && bally >= 475) {

                ballySpeed = -7;
                score++;

            }

            if (bally >= 700 ) {

                score = 0;
                bally = 30;
                gameOver = true;

            }

            // Window up
            if (bally <= 0) {

                ballySpeed = 7;

            }

            // Window right
            if (ballx >= 775) {

                ballxSpeed = -5;

            }

            // Window left
            if (ballx <= 0) {

                ballxSpeed = 5;

            }

            //i do not know what this means
            ballx1 = ballx1 + ballx1Speed;
            bally1 = bally1 + bally1Speed;

            // Window down
            if (ballx1 >= paddlex && ballx1 <= paddlex + 100 && bally1 >= 475) {

                bally1Speed = -14;
                score1++;

            }

            if (bally1 >= 700) {

                score1 = 0;
                bally1 = 10;


            }

            // Window up
            if (bally1 <= 0) {

                bally1Speed = 14;

            }

            // Window right
            if (ballx1 >= 775) {

                ballx1Speed = -10;

            }

            // Window left
            if (ballx1 <= 0) {

                ballx1Speed = 10;

            }


        **/i understand this has something to do with mouse events but i dont get the -50 part, and what is the overrides mean**
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            paddlex = e.getX() - 50;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
```

Comment: Don't post 200 lines of unrelated code if there are only a few you don't understand. Change your title to reflect which you don't understand and what you don't understand about them. Do the same in your question body. Voting to close as unclear for now.

Comment: What are the some parts which you don't understand?

Comment: If you want specific answers and help, then please **ask a specific question**.

Comment: I have added in specific parts/questions starting with **, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Seems like you are not understanding it as whole code and not just some parts. Grab a book and study - that's my suggestion

Comment: Yeah, your questions suggest that you need to understand some key rudiments of Java -- get a book, go through a tutorial, delete this over-general question.\

Answer (score -2, accepted):

@Override means that the code from the implemented class or "Super class" in your case "JComponent" will be overwritten by the sub-class implementing its methods. Your PONG class pulls the methods in and changes the ones it needs to alter from the super class to achieve its goal.

Overrides are required of all methods whether being altered or not.

imports are project dependencies.

main method is the beginning of your program; code is executed successively by the computer starting at the instantiation of JFrame working its way down line by line until timer expires and ends the program.

Comment: Thank you very much that helps set a few things straight!

Comment: No problem. Just a tip; if your questions are specific the answers you receive will be more helpful.